# Univocity parser using routines ignores the LongCoversion using defaultNullRead attribute?

Tags: univocity

I have below field configuration:

```
@Parsed(field="TEST_ID", defaultNullRead="000000")
private Long testId
```

now when the input file (csv parsing) contains value as NULL, it is not converting to default long value of 0, rather throws LongConversion exception for "NULL"

e.g. row in csv file: (5th column containing NULL is an issue)

```
7777|ab|444|PENDING|NULL|VESRION|TEST|11
```

I am using csvRoutines for parsing the input csv file

Comment: The upper case NULL is the cause. if it is lower case null works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NULL` in your input is actually text and not Java's `null`. You need to tell the parser to translate the string `NULL` to java `null`.

Add the following annotation (you can give it more than one string that represents `null`:

`@NullString(nulls = {"NULL", "N/A", "?"})`

Hope this helps